# Generic Type to Configuration Value mapping in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have an interface for holding the connection configuration info for web service access:

```
public interface IServiceConnectionConfiguration
{
    string Username { get; }
    string Password { get; }
    string ChannelEndpointUrl { get; }
    string MediaEndpointUrl { get; }
    string PlayerlEndpointUrl { get; }
    string PlaylistEndpointUrl { get; }
}
```

I have a factory class that returns the service instance specific to the type of the service requested.

```
public static class ServiceClientFactory
{
    public static void Configure(IServiceConnectionConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
    public static T GetService<T>() where T : class, IServiceClient
    {
    }
}
```

The factory is called as

```
Channel channelService   = factory.GetService<Channel>();
```

What I am trying to figure out is an elegant way for the Factory code to resolve the endpoint urls for the passed in types itself based on the config object passed during initialization. eg. If the type parameter passed is channel, it should take the ChannelEndpointUrl while constructing the ChannelService.

I thought about using attributes on the config class to decorate the endpoint urls with the service type that they correspond to but it seems like a bad design.

Any ideas.

Comment: A side note: you should be using [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) and not System.String to store a password.  A SecureString is kept encrypted in memory and is therefore a much better guard of the password if the program crashes and memory dumps, among other situations.

Comment: @Adam SecureString can be broken by several tools, and frankly is a bit of a PITA to work with. It has *uses*, but the first question should be "what scenario am I guarding this from? where did this password come from?" - in many cases it could be completely pointless using SecureString.

Comment: What is the best way to store a password in a config file. Then may be I can use a secure string to work with in the application.

Comment: @snkar If the password is stored in clear text, using SecureString isn't going to do you any good, because an attacker will go after the config file first and the contents of the program's memory second.  Even if the password is encrypted, the attacker might replicate the program's decryption logic, and get around your program's memory altogether.  In general, the best way to keep your password safe is to let the OS and .NET framework manage it.  For instance, it's possible to connect to SQL Server using the credentials of the currently logged-in user, which gets around this issue.

Comment: @MarcGravell Agreed 100%.  But this question doesn't say anything about modeling the attacker, so it's hard to tell whether SecureString is appropriate here or not.  If the password is stored in a config file, then as I said in the comment above SecureString is pretty much pointless.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin Thanks a lot for the suggestion. In my future projects I will try to use the technique you have mentioned, In any case, the current application is just a throw away POC. But, nice point on the secure string info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one way to approach it would be to have the Factory have a private static Dictionary containing your initialization logic, indexed by "Type". Similar to a strategy pattern.

for example:

```
public static class ServiceClientFactory
{
    private static IServiceConnectionConfiguration _config;
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<IServiceClient>> Initializers = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IServiceClient>>();

    static ServiceClientFactory()
    {
        Initializers.Add(typeof(Channel), () =>
                                               {
                                                   return //create the service client based on the endpoint
                                               });
    }

    public static void Configure(IServiceConnectionConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public static T GetService<T>() where T : class, IServiceClient
    {
        return (T)Initializers[typeof (T)]();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Now, as you mentioned, you cannot instantiate explicitly in your factory since you'd cause a circular reference, maybe you can force a new() constraint, and construct the instance in the GetService method, and only use the dictionary for endpoint configuration, such as:

```
public static class ServiceClientFactory
{
    private static IServiceConnectionConfiguration _config;
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<IServiceClient>> Initializers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<IServiceClient>>();

    static ServiceClientFactory()
    {
        Initializers.Add(typeof(Channel), t =>
                                              {
                                                  t.Url = _config.ChannelEndpointUrl;
                                                  //configure t using the appropriate endpoint
                                              });
    }

    public static void Configure(IServiceConnectionConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public static T GetService<T>() where T : class, IServiceClient, new()
    {
        var service = new T();
        Initializers[typeof(T)](service);
        return service;
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I cannot reference the service implementation class in the factory as then I will have a circular reference issue. The factory should resolve the service class runtime based on the type parameter passed in to the GetService call.

Comment: I just edited above to provide an alternate implementation, which creates the instances based on the new() constraint, and uses the dictionary solely for configuration purposes.

Comment: I guess I was not clear before. The problem lies with the line: Initializers.Add(typeof(**Channel**) ... I cannot have the Channel class referenced in the factory because it would cause a circular reference issue.

Comment: Now, if all you really need to do for each one, is just to set the Url, you can probably simplify it quite a bit, such as instead of having a dictionary of actions that configure, just have a dictionary of Func<string> that returns the Url, such as: ()=> _config.ChannelEndpointUrl

Comment: I see...so, in that case, wouldn't it just be much cleaner to have IServiceClient declare a void Configure(IServiceConnectionConfiguration config), and have each service take whichever setting is appropriate for it? And disregard the dictionary all-together. You cannot have specific behavior when you are not aware of the types themselves.

Comment: That was exactly my idea ... but i am not being able to figure out how would I achieve each service taking whichever setting is appropriate for it. Because there is no way that I can map: Channel -- ChannelEndPointUrl, Media -- MediaEndpointUrl, excepting by checking class names which seems like a really bad idea

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12014/discussion-between-snkar-and-pablo-romeo)